# php preg match find string inside " " with limit

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

This is my text:

```
pagination},queryId:"472f257a40c653c64c666ce877d59d2b", val:"598f257a40c653c64c666ce877d59d2b"
```

I need to find **472f257a40c653c64c666ce877d59d2b** and **598f257a40c653c64c666ce877d59d2b**.

These are all between ". I need ONLY strings between " ", and which don't exceds 32.

Here is my code:

```
preg_match_all('/"^(.*?){32}$"/mis', $get, $results);
```

Comment: Use `preg_match_all('~"([^"]+)"~', $s, $m)` -> `$m[1]` will hold the values.

Comment: You can use `(?<=:")[^"]{1,32}(?=")` or `:\s*"\K[^"]{1,32}(?=")` if there's a possibility of whitespace after the colon

Comment: Viktor, as I mentioned I need limit. My input string is too long and your code returns me lof of results

Comment: That looks like JSON. Are you cutting out part of the string?

Comment: No it is javascript. And I need to find all MD5 hashes which between "  "

Comment: because I need to do it on PHP, not javascript. Input string is javascript.

Comment: *Input string is javascript* - json_decode()

Comment: How? There are many functions on input string.

Comment: `(?<=")[\da-f]{1,32}(?=")` change `1` to min length

Comment: @AyxanƏmiraslanlı Remove `^` and `$` from your regex, they won't match. Also limit to hex characters only using character class. My attempt is: `preg_match_all('/"([0-9a-f]{32})"/mis', $get, $results)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regex**: `"([a-z0-9]{32})"` or `(?<=")[a-z0-9]{32}(?=")`

```
$text = "pagination},queryId:\"472f257a40c653c64c666ce877d59d2b\", val:\"598f257a40c653c64c666ce877d59d2b\"";

preg_match_all("/\"([a-z0-9]{32})\"/", $text, $match);
print_r($match);
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => "472f257a40c653c64c666ce877d59d2b"
            [1] => "598f257a40c653c64c666ce877d59d2b"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 472f257a40c653c64c666ce877d59d2b
            [1] => 598f257a40c653c64c666ce877d59d2b
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`:"\K[a-f\d]{32}(?=")`](https://regex101.com/r/H7LWMj/1)

**Explanation**

- Match `:"`
- Reset the starting point of the reported match `\K`
- Match characters from a to f and from 0 to 9 `[a-f\d]{32}`
- A positive lookahead that asserts what follows is a " `(?=")`

For example:

```
$re = '/:"\K[a-f\d]{32}(?=")/';
$str = 'pagination},queryId:"472f257a40c653c64c666ce877d59d2b", val:"598f257a40c653c64c666ce877d59d2b"';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

That would result in:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(32) "472f257a40c653c64c666ce877d59d2b"
  [1]=>
  string(32) "598f257a40c653c64c666ce877d59d2b"
}
```

[Output php example](https://3v4l.org/W5MYt)